# Is it possible to store the type of an object in a map for casting purposes

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Sorry for the confusing title as I am not sure how to word it.
What I am trying to do is basically cast to a type that will dynamically retrieved from a map. (The map will not have an instance but will have a type if that is possible)

Allow me to explain with an example.
Suppose I have a base class called `baseFoo`

```
class baseFoo
{
}
```

and then I have two different classes that inherit from baseFoo called `derFooA` and `derFooB`

```
class derfooA : public baseFoo
{
}
```

and similarly for `derfooB`

```
class derfooB : public baseFoo
{
}
```

Now I wanted to know if I can only store a type in a map (not an instance of type - simply a variable type) something like this

```
//STATEMENT A:
std::map<std::string , baseFoo> myMap= {{"derfooA",derfooA}, {"derfooB", derfooB}};
```

Then I would like to do something like this:

say I have a `baseFoo` ptr and I would like to DownCast the ptr to a specific type based on a string.  So I could do this:

```
std::string str = "derfooA";
derfooA* dfoo = dynamic_cast<myMap[str]>(baseFoo_ptr)
```

Now my question is if such a mechanism is possible what would my statement a look like ?

Comment: The `derFooA` in the `dynamic_cast` statement suggests you know the target type, so why look it up in a map?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need the downcast?

Comment: I am trying to cast to a specific type , this type would be determined from a string. In order to accomplish this i would liek to map a string to a type for that purpose i am using a map

Comment: So basically cast to a specific type determined from a string

Comment: @JamesFranco Yes, but why. To do what with?

Comment: But you can't have a pointer whose type isn't known at compile time...

Comment: _"please bare with me"_ This isn't really the place...

Comment: I know the base type of the pointer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll remove that part

Comment: What Barry and I are getting at is that you have some muddy thinking not so much near your Statement A as near your `dynamic_cast`.  What do you think the type of the expression `dynamic_cast<myMap[str]>(baseFoo_ptr)` should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class...Ts>
struct types { using type=types; };
```

this is a bundle of types.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){}; using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

this is a type tag.

```
template<class T, class U>
T* tag_dynamic_cast( tag_t<T>, U* u ) {
  return dynamic_cast<T*>(u);
}
template<class T, class U>
T& tag_dynamic_cast( tag_t<T>, U& u ) {
  return dynamic_cast<T&>(u);
}
```

this lets you dispatch a dynamic cast based on a tag.

```
template<class F, class Sig>
struct invoker;
template<class F, class R, class...Args>
struct invoker<F, R(Args...)> {
  R(*)(void*, Args...) operator()() const {
    return [](void* ptr, Args...args)->R {
      return (*static_cast<F*>(ptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
};
template<class F, class...Sigs>
std::tuple<Sigs*...> invokers() {
  return std::make_tuple( invoker<F, Sigs>{}()... );
}
```

so at this point we have a tuple of pointers to functions that will invoke a given object `F` type with a set of signatures `Sigs` for each signature.

We next would write a dipatcher which would select the "right" `Sigs` from `Sigs...` based on some call to it based on a `std::tuple` of `Sigs*` with a `void*` first argument.

Now we take a `types<...>` of the types you want to support to cast-to.  We use that to generate a type-erasure class which stores a passed-in lambda in a `std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>`.  The signatures we support are `tag_t<x>` where `x` varies over the types in `types<x...>`.

This is your dynamic dispatcher.

We are most of the way there.  Next we build something that takes a dynamic dispatcher and a `void*`, and invokes it with `tag_t<x>`.  It erases which `tag_t<x>` it will invoke the dynamic dispatcher with so the interface doesn't expose it.  It is basically a binder to a std function at this point, easy.

```
//STATEMENT A:
std::map<std::string , helper<derFooA, derFooB>> myMap=
  {{"derfooA",tag<derfooA>}, {"derfooB", tag<derfooB>}}; 
myMap[str]( [&](auto&& tag) {
  auto* dfoo = tag_dynamic_cast(tag, baseFoo_ptr);
} );
```

and while the lambda will be instantiated for every derived type, the only one that will be *run* is the one matching the value stored in the map.

You'll note you are trapped within the lambda.  Yep.  You cannot "leak" real type information out either, other than as run-time state.

Now, odds are your real problem has an easier solution.  But this is a roadmap to how to do it.  It would take me too much time to write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Store the type inside the instance, something like this:

```
class baseFoo
{
public:
class enum eClass
{
   a,
   b,
} myType;

baseFoo( eClass type )
: myType( type )
{}
eClass getType() { return myTpe; }|
};

class derfooA : public baseFoo
{
public:
  derfooA()
  : baseFoo( baseFoo::eClass::a )
  {}
};

...

baseFoo * ptr;

...

switch( ptr->getType() ) {
  case baseFoo::eClass::a:
    ... do something
```